# Push Notifications from java server

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Can anyone explain me the full process of push notification when I want to send a notification from server (java) to Firebase than to devices?

In my below example, the result is Android Notification Response :

```
{
    "multicast_id":7880177496704383133,
    "success":0,
    "failure":1,
    "canonical_ids":0,
    "results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]
 }
```

which is due to wrong "TO" Value,where this value came from ?

I already create a dummy Firebase project contains
  package com.push.notification;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import net.sf.json.JSONException;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

public class FCM {

final static private String FCM_URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";



/**

 * 

 * Method to send push notification to Android FireBased Cloud messaging 
 Server.

 * 

 * @param tokenId Generated and provided from Android Client Developer

 * @param server_key Key which is Generated in FCM Server 

 * @param message which contains actual information.

 * 

 */

static void send_FCM_Notification(String tokenId, String server_key, String 
message){



    try{

        // Create URL instance.

        URL url = new URL(FCM_URL);



        // create connection.

        HttpURLConnection conn;

        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();



        conn.setUseCaches(false);

        conn.setDoInput(true);

        conn.setDoOutput(true);



        //set method as POST or GET

        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");



        //pass FCM server key

        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization","key="+server_key);



        //Specify Message Format

        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");



        //Create JSON Object & pass value

        JSONObject infoJson = new JSONObject();

        infoJson.put("title","Here is your notification.");

        infoJson.put("body", message);



        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        json.put("to",tokenId.trim());

        json.put("notification", infoJson);



        OutputStreamWriter wr = new 
         OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

        wr.write(json.toString());

        wr.flush();

        int status = 0;

        if( null != conn ){

            status = conn.getResponseCode();

        }

        if( status != 0){



            if( status == 200 ){

                //SUCCESS message

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
                 InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

                System.out.println("Android Notification Response : " + 
                 reader.readLine());

            }else if(status == 401){

                //client side error

                System.out.println("Notification Response : TokenId : " + 
                  tokenId + " Error occurred :");

            }else if(status == 501){

                //server side error

                System.out.println("Notification Response : [ 
                errorCode=ServerError ] TokenId : " + tokenId);

            }else if( status == 503){

                //server side error

                System.out.println("Notification Response : FCM Service is 
                    Unavailable  TokenId : " + tokenId);

            }
        }

    }catch(MalformedURLException mlfexception){

        // Prototcal Error

        System.out.println("Error occurred while sending push 
             Notification!.." + mlfexception.getMessage());

    }catch(IOException mlfexception){

        //URL problem

        System.out.println("Reading URL, Error occurred while sending push 
             Notification!.." + mlfexception.getMessage());

    }catch(JSONException jsonexception){

        //Message format error

        System.out.println("Message Format, Error occurred while sending 
              push Notification!.." + jsonexception.getMessage());

    }catch (Exception exception) {

        //General Error or exception.

        System.out.println("Error occurred while sending push 
        Notification!.." + exception.getMessage());

    }

}
```

}

Comment: the 'TO' value comes from android device. Your application is responsible to generate a firebase token, with the help of that token your can send push notification from your java server to firebase then to your application. server->firebase->app

Comment: First create  Firebase project using firebase admin console, and get your fcm server key that will be used to send notification to any connected client applications(like your own android apps or web applications). Now register your that your android app with that your firebase created project. Now using android app, you can request a device token from FCM, and that should be forward to your server application(server application will used that device token as 'To' parameter)